# Alinear Input y Button verticalmente

Tags: html, css, html5

Tengo un pequeño problema con los input y el button, no he podido alinearlos perfectamente, de hecho por defecto quedan así:

[image: Imagen del input y boton]

Éste es el código que estaba usando:

```css
.searchcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchcontainer">
  <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
      <mat-label class="m-0 p-0">Fecha Evento</mat-label>
      <input matInput type="text" formControlName="FechaConvenio">
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-xl-2">
    <button mat-raised-button type="button" color="accent" class="btn-small btn-small-fix"> Aceptar </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que quiero es básicamente subir el botón "Aceptar" para que quede a la altura del `input`. ¿Cómo puedo hacer esto?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Alinear vertical y horizontalmente al centro, a la derecha o la izquierda?

Comment: @BetaM En realidad que el botón "Aceptar" se ajuste con el input, es decir subir un poco más el botón

Comment: ¿Estás usando bootstrap? Si sí, ¿qué versión? En cualquier caso, el código compartido no es suficiente para reproducir el problema (al menos no para que se vea como la imagen que compartes). Me imagino que el problema se podrá solucionar con `align-items` y algún margen en el botón, pero sería ideal si pudieras añadir más información.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Como qué más ?? Estoy usando la libreria de Angular.... la verdad es que no tengo más codigo para eso

Comment: @JuanPablo he editado la pregunta para poner el código ejecutable. Si le das ahora mismo a "Ejecutar" verás que el código compartido no se ve nada como las capturas de pantalla que compartes. Tienes estilos que cambian los input y botón y, sin compartirlos, nos es imposible saber qué necesitas exactamente para resolver el problema. Preguntaba si usabas Bootstrap porque los nombres de las clases compartidas son comunes a Bootstrap, pero si estás usando otra biblioteca de estilos, por favor indica cuál es.